# Why UICollectionView omit Line/Intrim spacing in Xcode 11 (ios 13)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionViewFlowLayout. For the same cell size, it's working fine but if size differs it's making LineSpacing and Interim spacing for UICollectionView Zero as shown in the image below.

Is there anything new in Xcode 11 (ios 13) that makes collection view change its behavior.

I have tried pragmatically as well as in storyboard but it didn't work.
Build with:

-------------------**Xcode 11.0**---------------------------------|------------------**Xcode 10.x**---------------------------

[image]

Comment: I say it's 50% reason of some changes on apple side (Xcode, ios13) and 50% something in your code. try to "attack" the problem from different way, start with 1 line, then add add only 1 item, one by one, and try to play with the spaces.

on code it's much safer then storyboard.

Comment: @user1105951 some internal problem. It was solved later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

Here Give how much spacing You want and also have a chance to do this in storyboard.